# What is the Best Way to Perform Timestamp Comparison in Bash

Tags: bash, time

I have an alert script that I am trying to keep from spamming me so I'd like to place a condition that if an alert has been sent within, say the last hour, to not send another alert.  Now I have a cron job that checks the condition every minute because I need to be alerted quickly when the condition is met but I don't need to get the email every munite until I get the issue under control.  What is the best way to compare time in bash to accomplish this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

By far the easiest is to store time stamps as modification times of dummy files. GNU `touch` and `date` commands can set/get these times and perform date calculations. Bash has tests to check whether a file is newer than (`-nt`) or older than (`-ot`) another.

For example, to only send a notification if the last notification was more than an hour ago:

```
touch -d '-1 hour' limit
if [ limit -nt last_notification ]; then
    #send notification...
    touch last_notification
fi
```

Comment: Note: I found -nt doesn't work unless there is at least a 1 second difference between the timestamps.  To test if a file was "new" I compared it to a temp file I "touched". I added a "sleep 1" in there to account for this -nt issue. It seems like this comparison is in fact the easiest way to go, but if you don't like my sleep suggestion you may want a more precise date/time comparison depending upon your needs.

Comment: Note that `-nt` is an extension to POSIX: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 22):

Use "test":

```
if test file1 -nt file2; then
   # file1 is newer than file2
fi
```

EDIT: If you want to know when an event occurred, you can use "touch" to create a file which you can later compare using "test".

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the -nt bit.  I could create a file when the alert is first tripped and delete it when the condition recovers (In that case I could just check for existence).  Any idea how I could implement the 'if it has been at least an hour throw the alert again' bit?

Comment: I believe @Bruno answered that.

Answer (score 19):

Use the date command to convert the two times into a standard format, and subtract them.  You'll probably want to store the previous execution time in a dotfile then do something like:

```
last = $(cat /tmp/.lastrun)
curr = $(date '+%s')

diff = $(($curr - $last))
if [ $diff -gt 3600 ]; then
    # ...
fi

echo "$curr" >/tmp/.lastrun
```

(Thanks, Steve.)

Comment: Why not just use seconds since the epoch (%s)?  3600 seconds in an hour.

Comment: I like this method, it is not depend on newer version bash. And busybox could do that.

Comment: I think you need backticks or `$()` on your call to date.