# LLVM HOW TO USE ALREADY COMPILED FILE?

Tags: shell, llvm

I have .so file already created of an LLVM pass.

Also I have the following script :

```
INPUT=${1}
LLVM_HOME=~/Workspace
if [ $(uname -s) == "Darwin" ]; then
    SHARED_LIB_EXT=dylib;
else
    SHARED_LIB_EXT=so;
fi

clang -emit-llvm support/${INPUT}.c -c -o support/${INPUT}.bc && \


    ${LLVM_HOME}/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/opt -load ../../../Debug+Asserts/lib/CS201PathProfiling.${SHARED_LIB_EXT} -pathProfiling support/${INPUT}.bc -S -o support/${INPUT}.ll && \
    ${LLVM_HOME}/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/llvm-as support/${INPUT}.ll -o support/${INPUT}.bb.bc && \
    ${LLVM_HOME}/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/lli support/${INPUT}.bb.bc
```

Since I already have my .so file I do not want the script to recompile my program as I already have the complied .so file.

Can anyone tell what changes could be made in the script so that it would work for my case. 
Thank you

Comment: Look how a Makefile works or just make a condition with `if [ -f xxx ]; then`

Answer (score 1):

Note: this question is not really LLVM-specific. You're asking how to make sure one file is newer than another (the *source* is newer than the **.so** built from it) and only then re-do some operation.

Bash lets you implement this with operators like `-nt` [see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205666/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-timestamp-comparison-in-bash) for one example].

That said, a better approach is to use a proper build system, such as `make`.